# Asymptotic of Riemann Sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to prove that $$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=\int_a^bf(t)dt+\frac{\alpha}{n}+\frac{\beta}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

where $f\in\mathcal{C}^2([a,b],\mathbb{R})$  for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569750/speed-of-convergence-of-riemann-sums).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
{b - a \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\fermi\pars{a + k\,{b - a \over n}}
={b - a \over n}\fermi\pars{b}
+ {b - a \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\fermi\pars{a + k\,{b - a \over n}}
$$
With $\it\mbox{Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula}$:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\fermi\pars{a + k\,{b - a \over n}}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{n}\fermi\pars{a + k\,{b - a \over n}}\,\dd k
-\half\bracks{\fermi\pars{a} + \fermi\pars{b}}
+
{1 \over 12}\bracks{\fermi'\pars{b} - \fermi'\pars{a}}{b - a \over n} + \cdots
\\[3mm]&=
{n \over b - a}\int_{a}^{b}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x
-\half\bracks{\fermi\pars{a} + \fermi\pars{b}}
+
{1 \over 12}\bracks{\fermi'\pars{b} - \fermi'\pars{a}}{b - a \over n} + \cdots
\end{align}
Can you complete it ?

Comment: What is the status of the $+\cdots$?