# Asymptotics of $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^n\sqrt{i(n-i)}}$ as $n\to+\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, special-functions

I am studying a bit of asymptotics and for practice I decided to find the asymptotic of the following,
$$s(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n\sqrt{i(n-i)}$$
as $n\to\infty$. This comes directly from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746734/need-to-simplify-formula-pi-sim-frac8n2-cdot-sum-limits-i-0n-s), where @Gary provided some hints in the comments:
$${\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt nz^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt n z^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{i(n-i)}}_{s(n)}z^n$$
but I am unable to finish the problem with this method  as I don't know how to find the $n$th Maclaurin coefficient. Feel free to also use any other methods to find the asymptotics (maybe Euler-Maclaurin), **but such an answer will preferably come after the original issue is resolved**. As a bonus, a derivation of the complete asymptotic expansion of $s(n)$ will also be nice to see.

Sorry for the long question. To outline:

1. How to find the $n$th Maclaurin Coefficient?
2. Alternative methods to find asymptotics?
3. Complete asymptotic expansion?

My attempt is below.

---

By [$(25.12.12)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#E12),
$$\begin{align*}{\rm{Li}}_{-1/2}(z)&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}(-\log\left(z\right))^{-3/2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(-1/2-n)}{n!}\log^n(z)
\end{align*}$$
which by Taylor's formula,
$$\begin{align*}
{\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)&=-\frac{\pi}{4\log^3(z)}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sqrt\pi\frac{\zeta(-1/2-n)}{n!}(-\log(z))^{n-3/2}+F(z) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{4(1-z)}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sqrt\pi\frac{\zeta(-1/2-n)}{n!}(-\log(z))^{n-3/2}+G(z)
\end{align*}$$
as $z\to1$, where $F(z),G(z)$ are holomorphic at $z=1$. Expanding the first term by its geometric series,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(s(n)-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)z^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sqrt\pi\frac{\zeta(-1/2-n)}{n!}(-\log(z))^{n-3/2}+G(z)$$
as $z\to 1$. Now the RHS is,
$$\sqrt\pi\zeta(-1/2)(-\log(z))^{-3/2}-\sqrt\pi\zeta(-3/2)(-\log(z))^{-1/2}+O\left(\sqrt{\log(z)}\right)$$
as $z\to1$, which by Taylor's formula,
$$\sqrt\pi\zeta(-1/2)(1-z)^{-3/2}+\sqrt\pi\left(\zeta(-3/2)-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(-1/2)\right)(1-z)^{-1/2}+O\left((1-z)^{1/2}\right)$$
as $z\to1$. Now all that is left is to extract the $n$th Maclaurin coefficient of the function above as,
$$s(n)=[z^n]{\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z).$$

Comment: Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118515/if-f-is-riemann-integrable-on-0-1-then-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-f/2121640), we have
$$\frac{S(n)}{n^2}=
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^n\sqrt{i(n-i)}=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)}=...$$
considering $f(x)=\sqrt{x(1-x)}$
$$...=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^nf\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
As a [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20sqrt%28x%281-x%29%29%20on%200%2C1)
$$\frac{S(n)}{n^2} \to \int_0^1f(x)dx=\frac{\pi}{8}, n\to\infty$$
So $$S(n) \sim \frac{\pi}{8} \cdot n^2$$
Does this work?

Comment: @rtybase. Yes, this works as an alternative method to the one I've outlined in my question. This doesn't allow for the higher order asymptotics though.

Comment: Except for the very first term of the asymptotic expansion, namely $\frac{\pi}{8}n^2$, I believe the problem is too dangerously close to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem to be simple to tackle.

Comment: Heuristically, $S(n) \sim \frac \pi 8 n^2- k  \sqrt n$ where $k\sim \frac 3 7$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Gary finds the coefficient of the second term,
$$2\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx 0.415772$$
which is indeed close to your approximate,
$$-k=-\frac{3}{7}\approx-0.428571$$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/627535) shows you how to get the asymptotic expansion.

Comment: Use the Cauchy integral formula for the Maclaurin coefficients and proceed as I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626126).

Comment: @Gary. I am having trouble using the Hankel contour. Could you guide me on how to find where ${\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)$ is analytic on, and it's asymptotic behaviour as $z\to\infty$? I just applied Cauchy's integral formula. $$s(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{(0+)}\frac{{\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)}{z^{n+1}}\ dz$$

Comment: Never mind, I think I got it.

Comment: @Gary. After collapsing the contour back to the positive real axis, how do I extract the contribution from the origin? I tried using Cauchy's integral formula but it gives me a divergent result.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger. It seems weird that the $\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}$ term only appears after the third term. I may have to recheck my work.

Comment: @bob I think the error is mine; it should cancel with the offset Gamma term in the numerator. Let me double-check.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Given the final answer
\begin{align*}
s(n)\sim{}&\frac\pi8n^2-2\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)\sqrt n-\zeta\left(-\frac32\right)\frac1{\sqrt n}\\
&-\frac14\zeta\left(-\frac52\right)\frac1{n\sqrt n}-\frac18\zeta\left(-\frac72\right)\frac1{n^2\sqrt n}\\
&-\frac5{64}\zeta\left(-\frac92\right)\frac1{n^3\sqrt n}-\frac7{128}\zeta\left(-\frac{11}2\right)\frac1{n^4\sqrt n}-\dotsb,
\end{align*}
does this impact the Gauss problem at all?

Comment: Here's a Desmos graph with the asymptotic expansion. Slide around the $n$ slider to see how $f(n)$ (exact) and $g(n)$ (asymptotic) match. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tpknap1vcq

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger. Thank you, that is very neat.

Answer (score 6):

**Derivation of full asymptotic expansion (thank you @Gary)**

Using the $n$th coefficient extraction operator $[z^n]$,
$$\begin{align*}s(n)&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sqrt{i(n-i)}=[z^n]\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt nz^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sqrt n z^n\right)=[z^n]{\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)\end{align*}$$
therefore by [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula),
$$s(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{(0+)}\frac{{\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)}{z^{n+1}}\ dz$$
for $n\ge1$. Now ${\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [1,+\infty)$  and $O(\log z)$ as $z\to\infty$; thus the integral along the arc vanishes and we are left with,
$$s(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mathscr {H^+}}\frac{{\rm Li}_{-1/2}^2(z)}{z^{n+1}}{\ dz}$$
where $\mathscr{H^+}$ is the [Hankel contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_contour) surrounding $[1,+\infty)$. Making the substitution $z\mapsto e^s$,
$$s(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\mathscr{H}e^{-ns}\operatorname{Li}_{-1/2}^2(e^s)\ ds$$
where $\mathscr{H}$ is the Hankel contour surrounding $[0,+\infty)$. Note that by [$(25.12.12)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#E12),
$${\rm{Li}}^2_{-1/2}\left(e^s\right)=-\frac{\pi}{4}s^{-3}+\sqrt \pi  \zeta \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)( - s)^{ - 3/2}  + F(s)$$
where $F(s)=o(1)$ as $s\to 0$. We can integrate these first two terms along the Hankel contour,
$$-\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mathscr{H}}s^{-3}e^{-ns}\ ds=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2e^{-ns}}{ds^2}\bigg{|}_{s=0}=\frac{\pi}{8}n^2$$
which is the leading order term, and with a change of variables $t=ns$ the next asymptotic term is,
$$\begin{align*}\sqrt\pi\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mathscr{H}}(-s)^{-3/2}e^{-ns}\ ds&=\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)n^{1/2}\frac{1}{2i}\oint_{\mathscr{H}}(-t)^{-3/2}e^{-t}\ dt \\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)n^{1/2}\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&=2\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)n^{1/2}
\end{align*}$$
where the [Hankel representation of the $\Gamma$ function](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/md327/fcm_3.pdf) and the well known value $\Gamma(-1/2)=-2\sqrt\pi$ was used. Now collapsing the contour back to the positive real line,
$$s(n)=\frac{\pi}{8}n^2+2\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)n^{1/2}+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^\infty e^{-nt}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(F(t+i\varepsilon)-F(t-i\varepsilon))\ dt,$$
with
$$F(s) = ( - s)^{ - 3/2} \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\sqrt \pi  \frac{{\zeta ( - 1/2 - k)}}{{k!}}s^k }  + H(s)$$
as $s\to 0$, where $H(s)$ is analytic at the origin. Taking the limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$,
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(F(t + { i}\varepsilon ) - F(t - { i}\varepsilon )) =  - 2{ i}\sqrt \pi  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta ( - 1/2 - k)}}{{k!}}t^{k - 3/2} } $$
hence by [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) we obtain the complete asymptotic expansion,
$$s(n)\sim\frac{\pi}{8}n^2+2\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)n^{1/2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(k-1/2)}{\Gamma(k+1)}\zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}-k\right)\frac{1}{n^{k-1/2}}$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: We have $$
{\mathop{\rm Li}\nolimits} _{ - 1/2}^2 ({\rm e}^s ) =  - \frac{\pi }{4}s^{ - 3}  + \sqrt \pi  \zeta \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)( - s)^{ - 3/2}  + o(1)
$$ as $s\to 0$. For the first two terms we can compute the integrals along the Hankel contours: $$
 - \frac{\pi }{4}\frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\oint_\mathscr{H} {s^{ - 3} {\rm e}^{ - ns} {\rm d}s}  =  - \frac{\pi }{4}\left[ {\frac{1}{{2!}}\frac{{{\rm d}^2 {\rm e}^{ - ns} }}{{{\rm d}s^2 }}} \right]_{s = 0}  = \frac{\pi }{8}n^2 
$$

Comment: and $$
\sqrt \pi  \zeta \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\oint_\mathscr{H} {( - s)^{ - 3/2} {\rm e}^{ - ns} {\rm d}s}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\zeta \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)n^{1/2} \frac{1}{{2{\rm i}}}\oint_\mathscr{H} {( - t)^{ - 3/2} {\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t}\\  =  - \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\zeta \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)n^{1/2} \Gamma \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right) = 2\zeta \left( { - \frac{1}{2}} \right)n^{1/2} 
$$

Comment: Then you integrate the terms hidden in $o(1)$ by collapsing the contour to the positive real line and using Watson's lemma.

Comment: @Gary. When I take the second derivative of $e^{-ns}$ wrt $s$, I get $n^2 e^{-ns}$, hence a sign error for the first term. What am I missing?

Comment: My mistake, the $-$ sign is not needed after the first $=$ sign.

Comment: @Gary. I am trying my best but I cannot figure out how you found the series expansion for $f(t)$ required for Watsons lemma in your answer. Could you help me in my answer?

Comment: Note that what remains after getting the first two terms is $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - nt} \frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} (F(t + {\rm i}\varepsilon ) - F(t - {\rm i}\varepsilon )){\rm d}t} 
$$ with $$
F(s) = ( - s)^{ - 3/2} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\sqrt \pi  \frac{{\zeta ( - 1/2 - n)}}{{n!}}s^n }  + H(s)
$$ near the origin. Here $H(s)$ is analytic at $s=0$. You found this in your original post with $H(s)$ corresponding to $F(\mathrm{e}^s)$ there.

Comment: @Gary. I see it now, I was confusing myself with too many functions. How do I deal with the limit $\epsilon\to 0$?

Comment: Can you see that the limit of that difference is $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} \left[ {( - (t + i\varepsilon ))^{ - 3/2}  - ( - (t - i\varepsilon ))^{ - 3/2} } \right]\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\sqrt \pi  \frac{{\zeta ( - 1/2 - n)}}{{n!}}t^n } \;?
$$ (note that $H(s)$ is single-valued). The limit in front of the sum should not be difficult.

Comment: @Gary. Thank you for writing it out like that, its much simpler than I thought. I should now have no more questions, and will write up the complete asymptotic expansion after I come back from dinner. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gary. Sorry for the delay. Does my result look correct?

Comment: @bob The coefficient of $n^{-3/2}$, which according to you should be $-\frac14\zeta\left(-\frac52\right)\approx-0.002129$, doesn't seem to check out numerically.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger. What should the correct numerical value be?

Comment: @bob Never mind!! Your value is correct. I simply didn't use enough decimal places for the $\sqrt n$ coefficient, and this was messing up values downstream. I was using $6$ decimal places, but for $n\approx800$ (where I was testing) I needed $10$.

Comment: You may add that $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0} (F(t + {\rm i}\varepsilon ) - F(t - {\rm i}\varepsilon )) =  - 2{\rm i}\sqrt \pi  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta ( - 1/2 - k)}}{{k!}}t^{k - 3/2} } .
$$

Comment: @Gary. I will do. Thank you!