# Is Riemann Sum increasing if $f$ is continuous, decreasing and concave?

Tags: riemann-sum

$$f: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R} \;\;  \text{(the set of real numbers).}$$
$$f(0) = 1\;, \;\;f(1) = 0$$
$$f \;\text{is continuous, decreasing and concave.}$$
$$ S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}.$$

Question: Is the sequence $S_n$ increasing?

Comment: Under the (further) assumption that $f$ is $C^2$, have you tried doing an asymptotic development of  $S_n$ to order $1/n^2$, in a fashion similar to that of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569750/speed-of-convergence-of-riemann-sums)?

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I don't know what 'asymptotic development of $S_n$' mean. Is it such like Taylor Expansion?

Comment: Yes -- see the link above.

Comment: Oh, I realize the link now.... Thank you!!