# Rate of convergence of Riemann sum under Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\sigma^2:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be Lipschitz. I want to show that:
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\sigma^2\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)-\int_0^1\sigma^2(s)ds\right)\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty
$$

I know that the sum inside the parenthesis converges to the integral, but I am not sure if the convergence is fast enough.

Is Lipschitz sufficient for that? Is this limit true? How can I show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be the Lipschitz constant of $\sigma^2$ and $1\le i\le n$. Then
$$
\Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\,\sigma^2\Bigl(\frac{i}{n}\Bigr)-\int_{(i-1)/n}^{i/n}\sigma^2(s)\,ds\Bigr|\le\int_{(i-1)/n}^{i/n}\Bigl|\sigma^2\Bigl(\frac{i}{n}\Bigr)-\sigma^2(s)\Bigr|\,ds\le\frac{L}{n^2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\,\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2\Bigl(\frac{i}{n}\Bigr)-\int_{0}^{1}\sigma^2(s)\,ds\Bigr|\le\frac{L}{n}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! That is a great answer! Just to make things a little more clear, when you bound the integral using Lipschitz, you are also using the fact that $0\leq\left|\frac{i}{n}-s\right|\leq\frac{i}{n}$, in order to get that $n^2$.

Comment: And that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|x_n\right|=0$.

Comment: It should be $\Bigl|\frac{i}{n}-s\Bigr|\le\frac1n$, and the fact that the length of the interval is also $1/n$.