# Calculate: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2n+k}{n^2+(2n+k)^2}$

Tags: limits, summation

Calculate: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2n+k}{n^2+(2n+k)^2}$$

I thought a Riemann sum could lead to something, but couldn't find a suitable partition.
Hint, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One may recognize a Riemann sum, by writing
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2n+k}{n^2+(2n+k)^2}=\frac1n \cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2+\frac{k}n }{1+(2+\frac{k}n)^2},
$$ then letting $n \to \infty$, to obtain
$$
\frac1n \cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2+\frac{k}n}{1+(2+\frac{k}n)^2} \to \int_0^1 \frac{2+x }{1+(2+x)^2}\:dx.\tag1
$$

*Add-on*. Since $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ with $f(x)=\frac{2+x}{1+(2+x)^2}$ satisfies $f \in \mathcal{C}^1([0,1])$, then one is allowed to apply the [standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569750/speed-of-convergence-of-riemann-sums/615573#615573)
$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) =\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx + \frac{f(0) + f(1)}{2n}+o\left(\frac1n \right) \tag2
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2n+k}{n^2+(2n+k)^2}=\frac{\ln 2}2+\frac{7}{20\: n}+o\left(\frac1n \right). \tag3
> $$

One may in fact express the given sum in terms of the digamma function, using
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+b}=\psi\left(n+b+1\right)-\psi\left(b\right), \qquad \text{Re}\:b>0,
$$ and writing
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2n+k}{n^2+(2n+k)^2} = \text{Re}\:\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+(2+i)n}
$$ then recalling the [asymptotics of the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation), as $n \to \infty$, one obtains

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2n+k}{n^2+(2n+k)^2}=\frac{\ln 2}2+\frac7{20\:n}+\frac1{300\:n^2}+\frac7{60\:000 \:n^4}+o\left(\frac1{n^5} \right).\tag4
> $$

Comment: Jee... So simple. Thanks!

Comment: @Yes You are welcome.

Comment: you is right , my mind not workin today hermano