# The rate of convergence of equidistant Riemann sum of a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Consider a continuous function $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, and the corresponding Riemann sum:
$$R_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
I am interested in the rate of convergence of the sequence $(\Delta_n(f))_{n\ge1}$ given by
$$\Delta_n(f)\stackrel{\rm def}{=} R_n(f)-\int_0^1f(x)dx$$
What we know is that this sequence converges to zero, and it is $O(1/n)$ if $f$ is of bounded variation. What  I am looking for are bad functions $f$, for example such that $ n^\epsilon |\Delta_n(f)|$ does not converge to $0$
for some $0<\epsilon<1$. Do you know of such creatures?

Comment: With $\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dx}{x \log^2 x}$  you should get $|\Delta_n| \sim \frac{1}{\log n}$

Comment: @reuns, do you think this is continuous at 0?

Comment: A first naive idea would be to look at the usual suspects -- simple enough continuous functions which are not of bounded variation, such as $x\mapsto x\sin\frac{1}{x}$. What does it give for that one?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569750/speed-of-convergence-of-riemann-sums

Comment: @ClementC. what I want are exactly functions that do not satisfy the expansion in the question you mentioned, as for $x\mapsto x\sin(1/x)$ it seems that the calculations are not easy to be done, maybe I will try some numerical calculations.

Comment: @FelixKlein Yes -- at least, the answer shows that such functions do exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we consider a sum $f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j(x)$ to be defined inductively.  I'll want to choose these so that for some increasing sequence $n_k$, 
$|\Delta_{n_k}(f)| > n_k^{-\epsilon}$.  In fact, I'll take $$\left|\Delta_{n_k}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}f_j
\right)\right| > 2 n_k^{-\epsilon}$$
and require 
$$ \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_j(x)| \le 2^{-j} n_k^{-\epsilon} \ \text{for}\ j > k $$
Given $f_1, \ldots, f_{k-1}$ and $n_1, \ldots, n_{k-1}$, let $B_k$ be the bound on $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_k(x)|$ arising from these.
Take $n_k$ large enough that $B_k > 2 n_k^{-\epsilon}$.   Let $g$ be a continuous function whose graph consists of narrow triangles of height $B_k$ centred at the multiples of $1/n_k$ (so that $R_{n_k}(g) = B_k$), narrow enough that $\int_0^1 g \; dx < B_k - 2 n_k^{-\epsilon}$.  Thus $\Delta_{n_k}(g) > 2 n_k^{-\epsilon}$.  Take $f_k = \pm g$, the sign chosen to be the same as that of $\Delta_{n_k}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} f_j\right)$, so that $\Delta_{n_k}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k f_j \right) \ge 2 n_k^{-\epsilon}$.

Comment: So your function is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k \text{ tri}(n_k x)$ with $\text{tri}(x) = |\lfloor x \rfloor - x -1/2|$ the periodic triangle ? And the series converges uniformly ?

Comment: No: **narrow enough that** ... So $g(x) = B_k \max\{0, 1 - r_k |x - j/n_k| \; : j = 0 \ldots n_k \}$ for sufficiently large $r_k$.  And yes, it does converge uniformly.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, This beautiful, thank you.